# Spring boot and Vaadin error build java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to initialize com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, vaadin

In build application (`mvnw spring-boot:run`)  I receive this error:

```
   2022-04-16 18:55:35.544  INFO 8980 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.60]
2022-04-16 18:55:35.835  INFO 8980 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-04-16 18:55:35.836  INFO 8980 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2810 ms
2022-04-16 18:55:36.088 ERROR 8980 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$CompositeServletContextListener]

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to initialize com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$VaadinAppShellContextListener
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$FailFastServletContextListener.contextInitialized(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:191) ~[vaadin-spring-23.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$CompositeServletContextListener.lambda$contextInitialized$0(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:213) ~[vaadin-spring-23.0.0.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541) ~[na:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$CompositeServletContextListener.contextInitialized(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:213) ~[vaadin-spring-23.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4766) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5230) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:478) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:211) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:182) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:160) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at com.example.crud.CrudApplication.main(CrudApplication.java:17) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Running project in development mode with no access to folder '/Users/alejandro/git/vaadin-add-ons/report-ui/add-on'.
Build project in production mode instead, see https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/flow/production/overview
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.AbstractConfigurationFactory.verifyFolderExists(AbstractConfigurationFactory.java:254) ~[flow-server-23.0.0.jar:23.0.0]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.AbstractConfigurationFactory.getConfigParametersUsingTokenData(AbstractConfigurationFactory.java:117) ~[flow-server-23.0.0.jar:23.0.0]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.DefaultApplicationConfigurationFactory.create(DefaultApplicationConfigurationFactory.java:121) ~[flow-server-23.0.0.jar:23.0.0]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.ApplicationConfiguration.lambda$get$0(ApplicationConfiguration.java:67) ~[flow-server-23.0.0.jar:23.0.0]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServletContext.getAttribute(VaadinServletContext.java:73) ~[flow-server-23.0.0.jar:23.0.0]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.ApplicationConfiguration.get(ApplicationConfiguration.java:50) ~[flow-server-23.0.0.jar:23.0.0]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$VaadinAppShellContextListener.failFastContextInitialized(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:543) ~[vaadin-spring-23.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$FailFastServletContextListener.contextInitialized(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:187) ~[vaadin-spring-23.0.0.jar:na]
    ... 41 common frames omitted

2022-04-16 18:55:36.089 ERROR 8980 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext   : One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
2022-04-16 18:55:36.091 ERROR 8980 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext   : Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
2022-04-16 18:55:36.376  INFO 8980 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-04-16 18:55:36.386  WARN 8980 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2022-04-16 18:55:36.404  INFO 8980 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-04-16 18:55:36.436 ERROR 8980 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at com.example.crud.CrudApplication.main(CrudApplication.java:17) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:478) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:211) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:182) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:160) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[] failed to start
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.rethrowDeferredStartupExceptions(TomcatWebServer.java:187) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:126) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
```

I have tryed to use the command to try to clean somethinks:

```
mvnw clean install
```

Or try to add or remove the line in pom.xml about the vaadin version:

```
<vaadin.version>23.0.6</vaadin.version>
```

No changes.
Maybe ther is a kind of imcompatibilities and I'm not able to see..
Below pom.xml.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.6</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>crud</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>crud</name>
        <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
        <properties>
            <java.version>11</java.version>
            <vaadin.version>23.0.6</vaadin.version>
        </properties>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>vaadin-addons</id>
                <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
                <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <optional>true</optional>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.vaadin.crudui</groupId>
                <artifactId>crudui</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.vaadin.reportui</groupId>
                <artifactId>report-ui</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>collaboration-engine</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                    <version>23.0.0</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>import</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>
    
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>
                                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            </exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    
        <profiles>
            <profile>
                <id>production</id>
                <build>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                            <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                            <executions>
                                <execution>
                                    <id>frontend</id>
                                    <phase>compile</phase>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
                                        <goal>build-frontend</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                    <configuration>
                                        <productionMode>true</productionMode>
                                    </configuration>
                                </execution>
                            </executions>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </build>
            </profile>
        </profiles>
    
    </project>
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 4):

The report-ui addon you are using contains a file called flow-build-info.json which is part of an application but should never be packaged in an addon. Your application *should* read flow-build-info.json primarily from the target folder in your project but apparently in your case it finds and tries to use the one from the addon instead.

Removing the addon should solve the problem. Ask the addon author to fix the addon.

Comment: Yes is it true, but I need the addon... That s mean that there is an hard coded mistake in the addon...